# Update table value when another table is updated?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, datatable

I am working with 3 tables in MySQL: `students`, `registration`, `courses`.

If under table `courses` I also have `student_ID` and `student_Name`, is it possible then if I update the the `student_Name` on the `students` table, it will also be updated on the `courses` table?

Or that when I insert a `student_ID` to the registration table, it will also insert the `student_name` that correspond with it to the column?

(all 3 table have the columns `student_ID` and `student_name`, I am trying to find a way to update the value on only one place..)

Comment: You just need to pass the student_ID column to other tables as an foreign key to prevent redundancy in the database. Because this approach of yours is completely unprincipled and superfluous

Comment: You should not have `student_Name` in the `courses` table, because it's not a course. It belongs only in the `students` table. You should find a tutorial or book on SQL, so that you learn to properly design your tables.

Comment: @MeysamAsadi Use code format for code. Names used in code are not code. Sometimes it can be helpful to format names used in code as code anyway but mostly it just makes text hard to read. But you should not introduce or remove such formatting because it is a matter of personal style & not necessity, don't change the author's style. Otherwise everybody would be editing back & forth between styles in every post. See [meta] & [meta.se] Q&A re this including the [SO FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/3404097). PS When editing please leave a reasonable summary of what you did & why.

Comment: I see that this is an issue for a lot of users so I will explain: I only gave this tables as an example(!). in my database I have a main DB and a sub-school-db's, so for example the main DB have a list of all students and all schools in the country. and then every sub-school-db have a list of the student that are studying in the current school. now I am trying to see if I can update the table in the main db and it will update it in the sub-school-db table. ok?

Answer (score 0):

you can make student_id field in all tables as field with primary index. ater it try to add this feild as foreighn key to other tables

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).